# Cannot access XML variables in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have a really stupid problem, but I can't access XML variables in my project.
I essentially copy pasted several tutorials, but I can't get it working. This is my code:

```
//Get level XML
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);      
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("/Levels/LevelXML.xml"));

        var levelXML:XML = new XML();
        function loadComplete(e:Event){
            levelXML = XML(e.target.data);
            trace("XML TRACE:" + levelXML.firstChild);
        }
```

In the loadComplete function, it doesn't recommend any of the variables, but does highlight them when I write them. So that means I can't get "data" in the first line, and I can't get "firstChild" in the second line. The trace just gives me a blank, not even NULL or anything.

I'm really stumped here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your XML as well.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. Flash doesn't give me the option to access the variables anyway.

Comment: Which variables are you exactly talking about? From XML? What is a variable there? Attribute? Node? Where is it placed in the hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't very clear. I meant I can't do levelXML.firstChild for example. It doesn't give me the auto-complete and it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: XML doesn't have a method called firstChild. That's an old AS2 version. There is a legacy class in AS3: XMLDocument which inherits this method from XMLNode (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Oh that's weird... I've looked at several AS3 tutorials and it said I had to use these functions. How does it work in AS3 then?

Comment: They were either terribly wrong, or you made some mistake. You should be using XML class and its methods for retrieving the children (XMLList instances). The docs are your best friend: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html You can also access it as levelXML.first_child_node_name.

Comment: post your xml as advised and try tracing the full xml first: `trace(levelXML)` in loadComplete. If that's prints correctly to the output panel, you can list the first node like so: `trace(levelXML.*[0])`;

Comment: Right... That's weird. I don't know why I didn't find this... I always google for extended amounts of time before asking. Anyway, thanks!